Having hotkeys for files in specific directories?
For instance, I want to have keymaps for Obsidian.nvim but only in my Obsidian vault (directory). If a file is located within the directory or any subfolders, then the hotkey applies, otherwise it doesn't. I know for filetypes you can put lua files in after/ftplugin/ to have keymaps for specific filetypes, but didn't find anything for directories. Is there a best or propery way of doing this?

In vim I would use :h autocmd-patterns:
...
The special pattern <buffer> or <buffer=N> is used for buffer-local
autocommands |autocmd-buflocal|.  This pattern is not matched against the name
of a buffer.

Examples: >
    :autocmd BufRead *.txt      set et
Set the 'et' option for all text files. >

    :autocmd BufRead /vim/src/*.c   set cindent
Set the 'cindent' option for C files in the /vim/src directory. >

    :autocmd BufRead /tmp/*.c   set ts=5
If you have a link from "/tmp/test.c" to "/home/nobody/vim/src/test.c", and
you start editing "/tmp/test.c", this autocommand will match.

Note:  To match part of a path, but not from the root directory, use a '*' as
the first character.  Example: >
    :autocmd BufRead */doc/*.txt    set tw=78
This autocommand will for example be executed for "/tmp/doc/xx.txt" and
"/usr/home/piet/doc/yy.txt".  The number of directories does not matter here.

...

I guess you can do the same or similar in neovim.
autocmd BufRead obsidian/vault/*.md nnoremap <buffer> gh :echo "GLHF"<CR>

or
vim9script

def MyMappings()
    nnoremap <buffer> gh1 :echo "mapping 1"<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer> gh2 :echo "mapping 2"<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer> gh3 :echo "mapping 3"<CR>
enddef
augroup MyGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead */obsidian/vault/*.md MyMappings()
augroup END

